# AWS Rekognition: An error occurred (ResourceNotReadyException) when calling the DetectCustomLabels operation: ProjectVersion

Tags: python, image, video, boto3, aiml

After creating a **custom label model** with Boto3 Recognition API, I am trying to use the model for prediction as follows:

```
from boto3 import client
rekog = client('rekognition')

def detect_labels(bucket=None, key=None, project_version_arn=None):
    response = rekog.detect_custom_labels(
           Image={'S3Object':{'Bucket':bucket, 'Name':key}}, 
           ProjectVersionArn=project_version_arn
   )
```

But I am getting the following Exception error: 
An error occurred (**ResourceNotReadyException**) when calling the DetectCustomLabels operation: ProjectVersion arn:aws:rekognition:
us-east-1:blah-blab-blal------ **is not ready**

I thought the ProjectVersion should be ready once the the model is created with a defined and available **project_version_arn**. Is there anything I have to do to make the model (project_version_arn) ready?

Answer (score 1):

You missed a step. You need to start the model to be able to use it. Keep in mind that you are charged every minute that the model is running.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/rekognition/latest/customlabels-dg/gs-step-start-model.html